# Broken Responsive Image

Tags: responsive-design

I must be missing something simple. While editing a plain Wordpress template I decided to add a background image to the header. I need the image to scale with the responsive design so I set my max-width to 100% and height to auto.. nothing displays. If I set the background to fixed dimensions that match the images native size (700 x 220) then all is good, unless I scale the site down or view on a mobile device. Please help! For reference, the site is portlandtoraleigh.com Thanks!

CSS:

```
.left-header{
background: url(images/headerimage.png) no-repeat;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title><?php wp_title( '&mdash;', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
    <div class="left-header">
    </div>

    <div id="comeon">
    <nav class="site-navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'semprul' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php
            esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'semprul' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content',
            'semprul' ); ?></a></div>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are doing this the more difficult method.  Try this:

```
<img class="left-header" src="filepath/image.png" />
```

then

```
.left-header {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't display. Check it out.

Comment: Remove the div tag surrounding it so that there is only the image tag.  Then change the image's src to 'http://portlandtoraleigh.com/wp-content/themes/semprul/images/headerimage.png'

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. My brain had been stuck in WP mode and I forgot the basics... Thank you very much, I am ashamed how much time I wasted on this!

Comment: No problem! Today I spend more time then I am willing to admit on a template :P

Answer (score 0):

Simple!
CSS

```
background-size:contain;
```

Hope I was helpful :)

**EDIT:** You may choose to use:

```
background-position: center center;
```

to center the background image both horizontally and vertically.

On side note, if your image does not display, try to add quotation marks in-between the parentheses; so:

```
url('pathtoimage/image.png');
```

Comment: I updated it, you may need quotation marks in between the url

Comment: That is because it is buried in Wordpress: http://portlandtoraleigh.com/wp-content/themes/semprul/images/headerimage.png

Comment: Ok! I haven't used WP in ages.  Try changing the url() to url('http://portlandtoraleigh.com/wp-content/themes/semprul/images/headerimage.png');  You may want to add a min-height to the image container just while you debug things

Comment: I know the path is correct, because it works fine when expressing a fixed dimension.

Comment: Type something into .left-header, like: <div class="left-header">Hello, World</div>  If the image shows, then you can just add color:transparent;

Comment: Hmm interesting, check out the site now. When I add text in the div, it displays correctly and you can see the header image behind it...

Comment: Ok, lets see if adding min-height:100px to .left-header will work.

Comment: It helps to display more of the image behind the text, but still doesn't address the image scaling to the div upon resizing. Thanks!